# Angular - Ionic $injector is empty on wp8 platform

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8, null, ionic-framework, angularjs-injector

I have a simple app' maked with angular in ionic (just "ionic start project").

And in my function 'Run' i've :

```
.run(function($injector) {
    console.log('->');
    console.log($injector);
     console.log('<-');}
```

The problem is that when i called $injector in console.log, i received an empty object so i can't do a 'get' (to call a factory).

And i don't have this problem on IOS, android, browser... Just with wp8 aka windows phone

Thanks,

Comment: Can we take a look at your factory?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your message, it was a javascript error somewhere in a factory...